# How to apply sorting asc desc on 3rd level association using ranksack in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ransack

I am using ransack gem for searching which's working fine but I have search creteria in which I want to search order based on products title asc or desc in line items.
It does not work and returns:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...wner_id" = $1 ORDER BY "orders"."created_at" ASC, lower(prod...
```

Parmas:

```
Parameters: {"filter_type"=>"", 
"csfname"=>"line_items_product_title_or_order_detail_name_or_shipping_address_postal_code
_or_billing_address_postal_code_or_line_items_product_sku_or_line_items_product_yan_or_line_items_product_ean_or_id_cont", "q"=>{"s"=>"[\"created_at 
asc\",\"line_items_product_title desc\"]", 
"line_items_product_title_or_order_detail_name_or_shipping_address_postal_code_or_billing
_address_postal_code_or_line_items_product_sku_or_line_items_product_yan_or_line_items_pr
oduct_ean_or_id_cont"=>""}}
```

Query:

```
@q = Order.joins(line_items: :product).where(products: {owner_id: current_seller}).ransack(params[:q])
    @seller_orders = @q.result(distinct: true)
```

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "orders".* FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "line_items" ON 
"line_items"."order_id" = "orders"."id" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = 
"line_items"."product_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "products" "products_line_items" ON 
"products_line_items"."id" = "line_items"."product_id" WHERE "products"."owner_id" = $1 
ORDER BY "orders"."created_at" ASC, lower(products.title) DESC
```

This below one works but it shows orders as 5 because 2 orders contains 5 line items in them and so it orders them based on that info.
How we can apply search but make distinct etc so orders would stay only 2?

```
@q = Order.joins(line_items: :product).where(products: {owner_id: current_seller}).ransack(params[:q])
    @seller_orders = @q.result(distinct: true).select('orders.*, lower(products.title)')
```

Comment: [Ransack Notes and explanations for distinction](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#problem-with-distinct-selects)

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks. I already tried these options!

Comment: Have you tried moving the `select` to the first line? e.g. `Order.select('orders.*, lower(products.title)')`

Comment: Yes I tried that and query became: `SELECT DISTINCT orders.*, lower(products.title) FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "line_items" ON "line_items"."order_id" = "orders"."id" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "line_items"."product_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "products" "products_line_items" ON "products_line_items"."id" = "line_items"."product_id" WHERE "products"."owner_id" = $1 ORDER BY lower(products.title) DESC` and still 5 records.

Comment: That means that each product has a different title which will result in 5 lines. I am not sure what your expected result is in this case because you cannot sort 2 orders by 5 product titles (at least not logically speaking). e.g. Order1: [A,H,Q], Order 2: [B,F,Z] which order comes first?

Comment: Yes you are indeed correct in saying that. Ofcourse, the client is very strict about his wireframes and asking to implement the same in backend so this happened. But your answer gave me trust to explain that to him. Thanks again for your help :)